# Cannot load translation catalog for Django I18n on Google App Engine Standard

Tags: python-3.x, django, google-app-engine, django-i18n, django-cache

I've set up I18n for my Python3 Django4.0 app and it runs locally without problems. When I deploy it to GAE standard the translated text isn't shown. The active language changes, but the text does not change.

The catalog files exist, but it looks like they are not being loaded.

I am aware that GAE-standard only allows access to `tmp/` directory. Could this be the reason? Are there particular cache requirements?

Any advice or examples would be super useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by an auto-generated .gcloudignore file including .mo files.

If the .mo file (created by running `makemessages`) doesnt exist, django wont raise any errors.